# how to customize route in Bing Map - save route/direction for future use

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm new in Bing Map, I'm trying to draw a direction between 2 waypoints

here is html page code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    #myMap {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 550px;
}
</style>
<body onload="GetMap();">
<div id="myMap"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function GetMap()
   {
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
    credentials: 'Ah21BgC5b223JVupbpDgKZjsT7ZSZ_cFzdhTxsBc8pVWP6fClhEeGznfJhtzBc3q',
    zoom: 18
    });
    var location1=new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.5079, -0.1247);
    var location2=new Microsoft.Maps.Location(51.5095, -0.1234);

    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
                //Create an instance of the directions manager.
                directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
                //Create waypoints to route between.
                var wp1 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({location:location1});
                var wp2 = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ location:location2});

                directionsManager.addWaypoint(wp1);
                directionsManager.addWaypoint(wp2);
                //Calculate directions.
                directionsManager.calculateDirections();
            });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

it is working and creating a direction between 2 waypoints.

my question is, is there anyway to change this route and save route/direction for future use.

I tried this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/articles/accessing-the-bing-maps-rest-services-using-php) but no luck.

any help will be appreciated.